# Using regex replace to add text to beginning of each line in multiline string

Tags: regex, go

I am trying to add a specific text to the start of each line. I am using the `^` regex operator to find the start of each line. However, I am only able to replace the first line of my multiline string. What am I doing wrong?

Exampe Code:

```
str := `This is a
        multiline
        string.`

var regexPattern = regexp.MustCompile("^")
s := regexPattern.ReplaceAllString(str, "START OF LINE")
fmt.Println(s)
```

Output:

```
START OF LINEThis is a
            multiline
            string.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the multiline flag `(?m)` to change the behavior of the caret `^` from "match beginning of string" to "match beginning of line":

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "regexp"

func main() {
    str := `This is a
            multiline
            string.`

    var regexPattern = regexp.MustCompile(`(?m)^`)
    s := regexPattern.ReplaceAllString(str, "START OF LINE")
    fmt.Println(s)    
}
```

Output:

```
START OF LINEThis is a
START OF LINE            multiline
START OF LINE            string.
```

Of course, the funny-looking output is an artifact of how you created your multiline string. You can use `(?m)^\s*` if you want to slurp up the leading spaces:

```
START OF LINEThis is a
START OF LINEmultiline
START OF LINEstring.
```